# Merge and split 2 rows into 3 rows in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I am preparing a form in word. I have inserted a 2x2 table. I have merged the rows in the 2nd column. I want to split the 2nd column into 3 rows. I have attached the an image for reference.

[image: Reference Image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Word will allow merging and splitting of cells in integer numbers (full cells) only.
You can use the following procedure to get the desired result:

1. create table with 6 rows and 2 columns (6x2 table)
2. In first column merge top 3 rows and then merge bottom 3 rows
3. Now in the 2nd column merge top 2 rows, followed by the next two rows and so on.
   Now you will have two column table with equally spaced rows (2 in first column and 3 in the second column)!
   Hope this is useful.